# str.split()[] - How it works?

Tags: python-3.x, split

I want to extract the next part (from '-') of the file name which is 000.xyz.
*N.B.* [file name is Axx-000.xyz]

```
def get_rank(xyz):                       
    pref = xyz.split('-')[1]             
    pref = pref.replace('.xyz', '')     
    return pref
```

If I try `get_rank('Axx-000.xyz')` which will return `000`.

I just started python lang I just want to clarify whether what I think how it works is correct or not.

So the first line of the function will split the string to list of strings.

1. if I do `get_rank('Axx-000.xyz')` `'Axx-000.xyz'` will turn into 
   `['Axx', '000.xyz']` then store 1st order element (`000.xyz`) as `pref`
2. the second line will replace/erase the string (.xyz) to nothing. so `pref = 000`

Is this correct process of the function?

Comment: You can always run it in a python REPL and see what you get as an output!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here is the explanation of this function, line by line.

`pref = xyz.split('-')[1]`: This line can be split in the following two lines:

1. `split_string = xyz.split('-')`
2. `pref = split_string[1]`

The first line means "look at the string and cut it wherever you find the character `'-'`. For example, for the string "Axx-000.xyz", the character is found once and splitted_string will be a list of 2 strings: `["Axx","000.xyz"]`.

The second line means "put in pref the second element of the list `split_string`.

Then the line `pref = pref.replace('.xyz', '')` call the method `replace`, which means: "look at the string and wherever you find the string `'.xyz'`, replace it by `''` (so nothing).

So the value returned by the function contains the second element of the table `["Axx","000.xyz"]` without `'.xyz'`, so simply `000`.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation is highly comprehensive and explicit! I appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

You define python function using `def`, inside of brackets there are argument of function that you define while calling it (e.g. `get_rank("Axx-000.xyz")`).

`pref = xyz.split('-')[1]` here you splitting xyz string by `-` and assigning splitted elements into array. `pref` variable gets value of index [1] of that array (second value).

`pref = pref.replace('.xyz', '')` here you simply replacing '.xyz' phrase with nothing `''`, otherwords you erasing `.xyz` from string.

On the last line you get final result - `000` string.